# Averaging values in another dataframe prior to a date in first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This I admit is pretty specific example. I have a two dataframes: the first has a date and group:

```
Date         Group  
06/11/2023     A   
05/11/2023     B   
04/11/2023     A   
03/11/2023     A   
02/11/2023     B
```

The second has dates, groups and values:

```
Date         Group    Value
06/11/2023     A        5
05/11/2023     B        8
04/11/2023     A       12
03/11/2023     A        4
02/11/2023     B        9
02/11/2023     B        0
01/11/2023     A        6
01/11/2023     B       10
```

Am looking to create an extra column in the first dataframe that simply looks at the backward average of the values for that group, but *before the date in question*.

So

- looking at the first row of the first table, Group A on 06/11/2023: the resultant average would be all the average of the value for all prior dates for Group A: i.e. 12,4,6 = 7.33.
- looking at the 2nd row of the first table, Group B on 05/11/2023, we'd have 9,0,10 = 6.33

My resulting table would look like:

```
Date         Group   AvgGroupValue_PriorDate
06/11/2023     A              7.33
05/11/2023     B              6.33
04/11/2023     A               5
03/11/2023     A               6
02/11/2023     B               10
```

I can see this would be a merge calculation but am struggling to understand how to do the "average prior to date by group" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is not correct (04/11/2023, A, 3.33). The value should be 5.00 (=[4+6]/2).

**Code:**

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Date'])

df2['CumulativeSum'] = df2.groupby('Group')['Value'].cumsum()  # cumulative sum of value for each group
df2['CumulativeCount'] = df2.groupby('Group').cumcount()       # cumulative count for each group
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['Date', 'Group'], how='left')
result['AvgGroupValue_PriorDate'] = (result['CumulativeSum'] - result['Value']) / result['CumulativeCount']
result['AvgGroupValue_PriorDate'] = result.groupby('Group')['AvgGroupValue_PriorDate'].fillna(0)
new_df= result[['Date', 'Group', 'AvgGroupValue_PriorDate']]
print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Date Group  AvgGroupValue_PriorDate
0 2023-11-06     A                 7.333333
1 2023-11-05     B                 6.333333
2 2023-11-04     A                 5.000000
3 2023-11-03     A                 6.000000
4 2023-11-02     B                10.000000
5 2023-11-02     B                 9.500000
```

Comment: Thanks - have edited my initial post!

Comment: And thanks for this solution - appreciate the others worked just as expected but I liked the cumcount() / cumsum() way about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options. First option, is to loop through rows of df1 and calculate manually. Like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["06/11/2023", "A"],   
    ["05/11/2023", "B"],   
    ["04/11/2023", "A"],  
    ["03/11/2023", "A"],
    ["02/11/2023", "B"],
], columns=["Date", "Group"])
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["06/11/2023", "A", 5],
    ["05/11/2023", "B", 8],
    ["04/11/2023", "A", 12],
    ["03/11/2023", "A", 4],
    ["02/11/2023", "B", 9],
    ["02/11/2023", "B", 0],
    ["01/11/2023", "A", 6],
    ["01/11/2023", "B", 10]
], columns=["Date", "Group", "Value"])
df2["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"])

# 1st option
def find_average_prior_date(row):
    avg = df2[(df2["Date"] < row["Date"]) & (df2["Group"] == row["Group"])]["Value"].mean()
    row["AvgGroupValue_PriorDate"] = avg
    return row

df1.apply(find_average_prior_date, axis=1)
>>>         Date Group  AvgGroupValue_PriorDate
>>> 0 2023-06-11     A                 7.333333
>>> 1 2023-05-11     B                 6.333333
>>> 2 2023-04-11     A                 5.000000
>>> 3 2023-03-11     A                 6.000000
>>> 4 2023-02-11     B                10.000000
```

This is the basic (but imho slowest) option because of the `apply` loop. Second option is to cross join two tables (join only on group), filter the rows, and then calculate averages.

```py
tmp = df1.merge(df2, on='Group', how='left', suffixes=['', '_df2'])
tmp = tmp[tmp['Date_df2'] < tmp['Date']].groupby(['Date', 'Group'])['Value'].mean().to_frame(name='AvgGroupValue_PriorDate').reset_index()
tmp
>>>         Date Group  AvgGroupValue_PriorDate
>>> 0 2023-06-11     A                 7.333333
>>> 1 2023-05-11     B                 6.333333
>>> 2 2023-04-11     A                 5.000000
>>> 3 2023-03-11     A                 6.000000
>>> 4 2023-02-11     B                10.000000
```

There is no significant difference in execution time with these small data frames. But you should try both options with your data and your environment. As the first one is slower, the second one is more memory demanding. It depends on your needs.

````py
%timeit df1.apply(find_average_prior_date, axis=1)
>>> 4.26 ms ± 335 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
tmp = df1.merge(df2, on='Group', how='left', suffixes=['', '_df2'])
tmp[tmp['Date_df2'] < tmp['Date']].groupby(['Date', 'Group'])['Value'].mean().to_frame(name='AvgGroupValue_PriorDate').reset_index()
>>> 3.41 ms ± 456 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

An efficient method to merge would be to use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) to merge the values, then [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

out = (df1.reset_index()
       .conditional_join(df2,
                         ('Date', 'Date', '>'),
                         ('Group', 'Group', '=='),
                         how='left', right_columns=['Value'])
       .groupby(['index', 'Date', 'Group'], as_index=False).mean()
       .set_index('index').rename_axis(df1.index.name)
      )
```

Output:

```
        Date Group      Value
0 2023-06-11     A   7.333333
1 2023-05-11     B   6.333333
2 2023-04-11     A   5.000000
3 2023-03-11     A   6.000000
4 2023-02-11     B  10.000000
```